# How to factorize a big number using Shor's algorithm with Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, shors-algorithm, factorization

There is codes for only modulus 15 in textbook. (function c_amod15)
So I tried to use the function `Shor` in library (`from Qiskit.algorithms import Shor`), but it said insufficient memory.
Specifically, I wanted to factorize 899 (= 31 * 29) but there showed `Insufficient memory to run circuit Shor(N=899, a=2) using the statevector simulator. Required memory: 67108864M, max memory: 16384M`.

How can I solve this problem?
If I want to factor a number other than 15, how can I fix the code in the textbook.
If I want to factor a big number (actually much more than 899), what function should I use?
Or I wish you can tell some resources to refer to.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE. Have you looked at the documentation: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/algorithms/08_factorizers.html ?